# PDFlib create_textflow --> Unknown option

Tags: pdflib

when I want to create a textflow with the sign "<" in the text I got an error:

```
$text = 'my test < text<nextline>and a new line';

$tf = PDF_create_textflow($pdf, $text, "fontname=Helvetica encoding=winansi fontsize=11 escapesequence=true fillcolor=black");

PDF_fit_textflow($pdf, $tf, 160, 110, 550, 50, ' minfontsize=8 fitmethod=auto');
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Unknown option 'text**

some ideas?

I already test some escapes without success =(

pdflib full version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'my test < text<nextline>and a new line';
```

the `<` is the starting character for an inline option. (as you do exactly in the next word with the option "nextline".)

There are in general two strategies to solve this:

- The most simple way, is to apply the `<` as a character reference `&lt;`. PDFlib will interpreter character references, when you set the option `charref=true`.
- you can redefine the option list begin character with the option `begoptlistchar`to a character which is not used in your text.

This is all described in detail within the PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 9.2.3 *"Inline Option Lists and Macros"*

I would recommend the first one.

Comment: that works perfectly !! I didn't know the option "charref=true" TANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just have similar issue and imo the best solution is to set -> begoptlistchar=none. It turns off inline optlist and you don't need to search for other character to redefine or replace < to lt; etc.

Regards